# Compare multiple tuples by elements

Tags: c++

I have an array of 3 tuples of 4 elements, and I need to compare their elements to see if all elements at index 0 are the same OR all unique, all elements at index 1 are all the same OR all unique, etc .. In other words, I need to see that all the tuples have either the same elements at index N or all unique elements at index N. The restriction is that each tuple only has 4 elements and they come in an array of 3 tuples.

I know you cannot iterate over elements of a tuple via a for loop, so I'm not sure what to do.

```
std::array<std::tuple<int, int, int, int>, 3> array_of_tuples;

for_each index of tuple in array_of_tuples:
    check if values at index of each tuple are same or all unique
```

Comment: You can write a function template that checks the condition for `I`th tuple elements, where `I` is the (non-type) template parameter.

Comment: I suppose you cannot change the used data structure? Because it seems not very well-designed to use a tuple for values of the same type that need to be iterated over...

Comment: I believe you have a typo: `std::array<std::tuple<int, int, int, int> 3>` should probably be `std::array<std::tuple<int, int, int, int>, 3>`

Comment: Sounds like you want something like [`std::equal`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/equal) with a custom predicate?

Comment: Or perhaps [`std::transform`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform) to get the elements from the tuples into a separate container, and then use it for checking equality or uniqueness?